# Issue with .change function in jQuery form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a script that changes the span text value depending on user input in the select menu.

I have a fault with my current script. How do I fix it so when I click 'End Date' and then click 'Start Date' again, it displays 'Start Date' in the span?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/197ncb10/

```js
$(function() {
  $('#usertype').change(function() {
    $(this).next("span").text("End Date");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="myhidden3" name="quantity" value="1" />
  <select id='usertype'>
        <option value='1'>Start Date</option>
        <option value='2'>End Date</option>
        <option value='3'>End Date</option>
      </select>
  <span>Start Date</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do

```js
$(function() {
  $('#usertype').change(function() {
     $(this).next("span").text($('#usertype option:selected').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="myhidden3" name="quantity" value="1" />
  <select id='usertype'>
        <option value='1'>Start Date</option>
        <option value='2'>End Date</option>
        <option value='3'>End Date</option>
      </select>
  <span>Start Date</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Shorter: `$(this).next("span").text($('option:selected',this).text());`

Comment: @anete.anetes Can you expand your comment a bit ?

Comment: Is it possible to target the span based on a class rather than just the next one? Example - I may have text in between: http://jsfiddle.net/197ncb10/5/

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Yes.. you may consider asking in another question. One step at a time :)

Comment: @ANS i see expression in my next 'value', so - i need to calculate it. When i store value in another variable i can use it again without calculate value. Jus think about it, it's more complex, general advice.

Comment: @mplungjan and i fixed it now. But i can do it faster then you, cuz your solution **not redable**.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk how about this: `$(this).next("span").text($('.maintanence',$('option:selected', this).is(':checked')).text())` it would be fine read too?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$(function() {         
    $('#usertype').change(function() {        
        let text=$(':selected',this).text();
        $(this).next("span").text(text);
    });     
});
```

Comment: That is much better :) - note `let` is ES5, `var` will work everywhere

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine the selected option and then the text inside that option.

```
 $(function() {         
    $('#usertype').change(function() { 
        var selectedText = $("#usertype option[value='"+ $(this).val() +"']").text();
        $(this).next("span").text(selectedText);
    });     
});
```

Check out this jsfiddle [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/197ncb10/4/)

Comment: Why so complicated?
 `$(this).next("span").text($('option:selected',this).text());`

Comment: Everyone has there own view and thought. I guess we are independent on stackoverflow to put what we think and the ways question can be solved @mplungjan

Comment: But yours is needlessly complicated.

Comment: @AKA If that is the case , there would be no comment section. As you said  `we are independent on stackoverflow to put what we think`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

Give id for span like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="myhidden3" name="quantity" value="1" />
  <select id='usertype'>
        <option value='1'>Start Date</option>
        <option value='2'>End Date</option>
        <option value='3'>End Date</option>
      </select>
  <span id='span_text'>Start Date</span>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#usertype').change(function() {
    $('#span_text').val($('#usertype  option:selected').text());

  });
});
```